# Angular2 - sa-datatable loads data only for the first time

Tags: angular, datatable, smartadmin

**The datagrid**:

```
<sa-datatable [options]="{
                data: bundles,
                columns: [ {data: 'srNo'}, {data: 'name'}, { data: null, defaultContent: '<button class=\'btn btn-default\'>Details</button>' } ] }"
                paginationLength="true" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-hide="phone">Sr. No.</th>
            <th data-class="expand"><i class="text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</sa-datatable>
<div> {{bundles.length }} </div>
```

**The component**:

```
Component({
    selector: 'tax-receipting-bundles',
    templateUrl: './tax-receipting-bundles.component.html',
    providers: [ TaxReceiptingBundleService ]
})

export class TaxReceiptingBundlesComponent implements OnInit  {
    bundles: TaxReceiptingBundle[];

    constructor(private service: TaxReceiptingBundleService) {
        this.bundles = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getBundles()
            .then(b=> {
                this.bundles = b; 
                console.log(this.bundles);
        });
}
```

**The service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TaxReceiptingBundleService {
    getBundles() {
        return Promise.resolve(TAXRECEIPTINGBUNDLES);
  }
}
```

**Mock Data**

```
export const TAXRECEIPTINGBUNDLES: TaxReceiptingBundle[] = [
    {id: 1, srNo: 1, name: 'Bundles for February 2005'},
    {id: 2, srNo: 2, name: 'CDN Bundles'},
    .
    .
    {id: 12, srNo: 12, name: 'Bundles for April 2004'},
];
```

When I navigate to the component containing the datagrid, it shows the data correctly (12 records).

However, when I navigate away and come back to the same component, the grid is empty. However, the `console.log` in the `ngOnInit()` always logs all 12 records. But they're just now showing in the grid.

But the `bundles.length` prints 12 under the table -

[image]
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the second time onwards, the `datatable` was getting rendered before getting the data for binding it with.

I tried using `setTimeOut`, but it didn't work. What worked for me was using a [resolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard).

I wrote an `resolver service` which returns a `Promise` of type `TaxReceiptingBundle[]` :

```
@Injectable()
export class TaxReceiptingBundlesResolver implements Resolve< TaxReceiptingBundle[]> {
    constructor(private cs: TaxReceiptingBundlesService, private router: Router) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<TaxReceiptingBundle[]> {

        return this.cs.getBundles().then(c => {
            if (c) {
                return c;
            } else { 
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                return null;
            }
        });
     }
 }
```

Used the resolver in the path that required it:

```
export const taxReceiptingRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TaxReceiptingBundlesComponent,
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Bundles Setup'
        },
        resolve: {
            bundles: TaxReceiptingBundlesResolver
        }
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(taxReceiptingRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [TaxReceiptingBundlesResolver, TaxReceiptingBundlesService]
})
```

In the component, instead of getting data from the TaxReceiptingBundleService, I got it from the route object.

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
        .subscribe((data: { bundles: TaxReceiptingBundle[] }) => {
            ..
    });
}
```

Now, the navigation waits for the list of `TaxReceiptingBundle`s.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem and have come up with a presumably simpler solution (although it still feels like a workaround).

In the component class, I defined a variable `dataAvailable` that is `false` by default and set to `true` once the data is loaded.

```
export class TaxReceiptingBundlesComponent implements OnInit  {
    bundles: TaxReceiptingBundle[];
    dataAvailable: boolean = false;

    constructor(private service: TaxReceiptingBundleService) {
        this.bundles = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getBundles()
        .then(b=> {
            this.bundles = b; 
            this.dataAvailable = true;
    }); 
}
```

In the component's html file, simply hide the table-widget until data is available:

```
<sa-datatable *ngIf="dataAvailable" [options]="..." ...>
...
</sa-datatable>
```

This doesn't prevent the page from being loaded, but just the table. I am still looking for a solution that works on the level of the sa-datatable-module or -component, so that in my components I can just use the datatables without any workarounds.